# How to setup Expo Deep linking

Tags: ios, expo, deep-linking, react-native-deep-linking

I set the `expo.scheme` to `"com.test"` in `app.json`. However I get an error when running the following commands:

`npx uri-scheme open com.test://192.168.0.8:8081/--/first-view --ios`

```
› iOS: Opening URI "com.test://192.168.0.8:8081/--/first-view" in simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code=-10814):
Simulator device failed to open com.test://192.168.0.8:8081/--/first-view.
Underlying error (domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code=-10814):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Aborting run
An unexpected error was encountered. Please report it as a bug:
Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 194
```

Is there anything else I need to set? I'm using local build (`expo run:ios`).

Comment: Have you rebuilt your custom client and installed the newly built app to your device/simulator?  Note: deep linking will not work with Expo Go.  You need to build your own custom client.

Comment: @GregFenton What do you mean `built`? I run it with `expo run:ios`

Comment: Yes I use expo with `prebuild`

Comment: Okay, good.  That is how you do a [local build](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/local-app-development/#local-app-compilation)  Your post didn't indicate whether you were using a custom build or using Expo Go.

Comment: @GregFenton Updated. Is there anything I need to check?

Comment: When the app gets installed it should register its URL scheme with the OS so that when the OS is given a URL to "open" it knows to call out to your app.  If the OS throws an error trying to open a URL with your scheme....that typically means the OS doesn't recognize that scheme (your app didn't register it correctly or registered some other scheme....or something)

Comment: [This app](https://github.com/wujianguo/iOSAppsInfo) is not maintained anymore.  I wonder if there's a newer project that does essentially the same thing: list URL schemes of all apps on your device.

Comment: Ahh... I resolve the problem. I re-did `npx expo prebuild` and it worked. I didn't know that I had to re-do the `prebuild` after modifying the `scheme`.
Thanks to you, I was able to recognize it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by not `prebuild`ing after changing the scheme. The problem was resolved after `npx expo prebuild`.

Comment: Whenever you change things that involve "native bits" (add/upgrade/remove NPMs, modify app.json/app.config.js) then you need to run `prebuild` in order to update the native projects (XCode and Android Studio).